# Configure systemd in mounted root (i.e. offline)

Tags: systemd, embedded

I am trying to bootstrap and configure an embedded system.  I need to enable certain systemd services (e.g. networkd, resolved).

I'm working on an x86* machine while the one that I'm configuring is an ARM machine - so I (presumably) need to use the host's systemd to edit the systemd configuration stored in the ARM's file system.

How would I do the equivalent actions which these do on the x86 host, in the offline ARM system which I have mounted?

```
systemctl enable foo.service

systemctl disable foo.service
```

Presumably `netctl enable <name>` is still doable as `systemctl enable netctl@<name>`.

Comment: I'm tempted to create the symlinks which `systemctl enable` creates, but I'm worried that there might be more to it than that and I'll leave systemd in an inconsistent state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the symlinks that `systemctl enable` would create. There's not more to it then that.